# Python re module prefix

Tags: python

I'm learning Python3 now and have come to `re` module. I want to write a pattern that searches the given string for Mobile Numbers. For Indian Nos.,
  `re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d')` should suffice. But Indian Nos. also 
use `+91` and `0` as the country code and I want to include those too in the result.
I've tried:

```
r = re.compile(r'(0|\+91)?\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d')
```

and it returns

```
['+91', '0', '']
```

As output for `r.findall(string)`. How to solve this problem?

Edit : string can be any text like 'no1 = 99xxxxxxxxxx, no2=+9199xxxxxxxxxx'.

Comment: welcome to SO. What is the string value ?

Comment: Replace `(` with `(?:`.

Comment: Do you wan't to match both of those strings?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can use limitation in order to specify the number of digits instead of typing them all. Secondly you can use non-capture grouping (by adding `?:` at the leading of your group) if you don't want the result of captured group separately.

```
r = re.compile(r'(?:0|\+91)?\d{9}')
```

Regarding the result of `re.findall()`, it will return all the matched groups include group 0 which is the result of matched string by the regex. And in this case if it did't return your string, it might be because of your input string that doesn't get matched with this regex.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I'm getting the required results using your code. Could you please give more Info on the ` : ` operator ?. I could'nt seem to find it.

Comment: @reek12 If it was helpful please consider accepting the answer. As I told that's a non-capture group sign, also it's `?:`  not `:`. Read more here http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 0):

Nice pattern for telefon numbers is

```
_pattern = \
    """
    ^                # string start
    [+]?             # optional "+"
    [\d \(\)]*       # a number of digits, blanks or brackets
    [/]?             # an optional slash
    [\d \(\)]*       # number of digits, blanks, brackets an this repeated none, once or multiple times 
    (([ ]?-)?        # optional: a hyphen and ...
    [ ]?[\d \(\)]*)? # ... an optional blank and optional a number of digits, blanks or brackets
    $                # string end
    """
```

This pattern does not catch each syntactial error. More information you find in [this web page](http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/phone_numbers.html).